# Are there examples of using reinforcement learning for multi label text classification?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, multilabel-classification

I have a labeled dataset and  I am going to develop a classifier for a multilabel classification problem (ex: 5 labels). I have already developed BERT, and CNN, but I was wondering if I could use RL for text classification as well.

As I know, using RL we can use a smaller training dataset

I am looking for a python code for RL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinforcement learning is a *different thing* from BERT or CNN. It is not actually a technique or a model, it is a **type of problem**(hidden markov models), and the set of techniques used to solve that problem.

More precisely, Reinforcement Learning it the class of problems where you have

- An **agent**
- who has to chooses **actions** to take
- Those actions will change its **state** and give it a **reward**
  Where your goal is to maximize the reward.

This fits very well with game AI, or robotics applications for example.

But in your case, you want to develop a classifier from a labeled dataset. That is **not a reinforcement learning problem**, it is **supervised learning**

Comment: Thanks @Nephanth for your reply. I have used a thesis in which they have used CNN as the function approximator in the Deep Q-Learning network for multilabel classification of text. but I could not find any sample code